# Listing latest modified sub-directories

Tags: scripting

So I'm trying to get the sub directory that was modified last.

IE.
1727 has 8 backups but I want my script I'm writing to only grep the contents of the latest backup directory. Every backup that gets run, gets a new subdirectory under the corresponding parent directory.

```
[root@localhost backups]# find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -not -empty -type d | grep -v logs
./1014/backup_1083219
./1014/backup_1082586
./1014/backup_1081955
./1014/backup_1081334
./1014/backup_1089443
./1014/backup_1080711
./1014/backup_1090690
./1014/backup_1091313
./1014/backup_1090062
./350/backup_1043735
./350/backup_1087678
./350/backup_1088301
./350/backup_1090170
./350/backup_222862
./350/backup_1059530
./350/backup_1088925
./350/backup_1091416
./350/backup_1089549
./350/backup_1090793
./1854/backup_1091300
./460/backup_1089536
./460/backup_1090781
./460/backup_1090159
./460/backup_1086423
./460/backup_1087045
```

I know I can append a | ls -td -- */ but that still doesn't help me with providing a list of the directories with only the latest sub directory

Ideally I'd want something like the following as the output (assuming the subfolders are all the latest modified ones)

```
./1727/backup_1059492
./1113/backup_862734
./881/backup_1088974
./1014/backup_1089443
./350/backup_1059530
./1854/backup_1091300
./460/backup_1086423
```

The more I think about this, I think I might need a while loop to work through all the directories and subdirectories but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

In `zsh`, you could do:

```
for d (<->(NF)) print -rC1 -- $d/backup_<->(N/om[1])
```

For the newest¹ `backup_xxx` subdir of each `yyy` dir.

Or:

```
for d (<->(NF)) print -rC1 -- $d/backup_<->(N/n[-1])
```

For the one with the highest number.

- `<->` matches any sequence of ASCII decimal digits.
- `(NF)`, `(N/n[-1])`... specify [glob qualifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers)
- `/` selects files of type *directory*
- `F` selects `F`ull directories (like `/` but excludes empty directories).
- `n` turns on `numericglobsort` for that glob, for numeric ordering when filenames contain sequences of decimal digits.
- `om` `o`rders by `m`odification time (from newest to oldest like `ls -t`).
- `[1]` selects the first, `[-1]` the last.
- `print -rC1 --` `print`s `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn.

Another approach could be to list those files from newest to oldest one per line and use `awk` to select the first of each top directory. That's OK here as long as we restrict the file list to files with such tamed name:

```
print -rC1 -- <->/backup_<->(N/om) | awk -F/ '!seen[$1]++'
```

(or `nOn` instead of `om` for highest `<number>` among `backup_<number>` subdirectories).

There's a difference with the previous solution in that it will follow the symlinks in the current directory, as if you had used `<->(N-F)` instead of `<->(NF)` in the previous approach.

With GNU `find`, it could also be done with:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -regextype posix-extended \
  -regex './[0-9]+/backup_[0-9]+' -type d -printf '%T@/%P\n' |
  sort -rn |
  awk -F/ '!seen[$2]++ {print $2"/"$3"}'
```

Or for highest `<number>` among `backup_<number>` subdirectories:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -regextype posix-extended \
  -regex './[0-9]+/backup_[0-9]+' -type d -printf '%P\n' |
  sort -t_ -k2rn |
  awk -F/ '!seen[$2]++'
```

---

To get those directories as one list so you can pass it to one `grep` invocation for instance:

```
(){ dirs=( $^@/backup_<->(N/om[1]) ) } <->(NF)
(( $#dirs )) && grep -re pattern -- $dirs
```

Or since the directory names are very tame here and don't contain any of the characters special to `xargs`, pick any of the solutions above and pipe to `xargs -r grep -re pattern --` (`-r` being a GNU extension, both for `xargs` and `grep` though with unrelated meanings).

With untamed directory names, you'd use NUL-delimited records (add the `-N` option to `print` or `-v ORS='\0'` to `gawk`) and add the `-0` option to `xargs`.

---

<sup>¹ Bearing in mind that the modification time of a directory is updated any time an entry is added / removed / renamed in it, not when data in any file within is modified, so it may not be what you actually want.</sup>